# como importar classes referenciando uma a outra em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, python-2.7

Estou com um problema na hora de importar classes em *Python*.
Veja, existem 4 arquivos:

**main**:

```
from classeB import ClasseB

ClasseB()
```

**classe A:**

```
from classeModelo import ClasseModelo

class ClasseA():
    Caminho = ""
    modelo = Modelo("","","")
```

**classe Modelo:**

```
from classeA import ClasseA

class ClasseModelo():
    def __init__(self, v1,v2,v3):
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
        self.v3 = v3

    def carrega(self):
        #Carrega valores nas variáveis da própria classe A
        #a partir do arquivo usando o caminho da classe A
        #open(ClasseA.caminho)
        pass
```

**classe B:**

```
from classeA import ClasseA

class ClasseB():
    def __init__(self):
        ClasseA.caminho = "caminho no pc"
        ClasseA.modelo.carrega()
```

Eu preciso usar os métodos da **classe A** na **Classe Modelo** e vice-versa, mas quando eu depuro ele entra em um *loop* infinito.

Comment: Se uma depende da outra, era de se esperar que entrasse em loop infinito, não? A questão é: por que ambas as classes dependem da outra?

Comment: E isto dá algum problema? Pode ser que tenha algum problema no seu código que não está sendo apresentado. Você tem que ser responsável para gerenciar a interdependência de acordo com sua necessidade. Não existe problemas em classes depender uma da outra, pode haver problema se quer que um objeto dependa do outro, porque aí depende do seu domínio, seu problema a resolver.

Comment: Eu irei alterar a pergunta para ficar mais claro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro - você está confundindo "classe" com "módulos".
Em Java, há uma especificidade da linguagemd e que classes públicas devem ser a unica classe pública em um arquivo do mesmo nome. Isso não tem nada a ver com "orientação a objetos" - é uma coisa do Java.

Em Python, um módulo é um arquivo com extensão .py . Em cada módulo colocamos quantas classes quisermos, públicas ou não. A independência ainda é mais marcada se forem seguidas as recomendações para nomenclatura: módulos devem ter o nome em minúsculas, e classes devem ter o nome em CamelCase.

Em alguns casos, dependendo da arquitetura do projeto, pode acontecer sim de precisarmos de uma "referencia círcular" - na sua pergunta: a ClasseA, definida no módulo_a precisar ter uma referência à ClasseB definida no modulo_b e vice-versa.

Nesse caso, como você bem notou, não dá para colocar os comandos de importação no começo do arquivo. (O Python não trava ou entra em Loop como você tenta implicar na sua pergunta - você pode ter um NameError de difícil verificação - mas se em Python você manda importar um módulo que está "importado pela metade", isso não dá erro - se você tentar usar um nome daquele módulo que ainda não foi definido no ponto em que está a importação, aí você tem um erro por que o nome não existe, e é só isso).

Então, o que você tem que ter em mente nesses casos é que: (1) O `import` do Python, depois da primeira importação de um módulo, simplesmente cria variáveis no espaço de nomes local, apontando para o módulo que você mandou importar.  (2) O código que está dentro do corpo de uma classe é executado durante a importação, mas o código dentro dos *métodos* de uma classe só é executado quando você criar um objeto daquela classe. Normalmente isso ocorre num ponto posterior da execução do programa, quando a inicialização de todos os módulos está completa.

Dito tudo isso, você pode perfeitamente fazer:

main.py:

```
import modulo_a, modulo_b

...
obj1 = modulo_a.ClasseA()
...
```

modulo_a:

```
...
class ClasseA:
    def __init__(self, ...):
         import modulo_b
         self.objeto_b = modulo_b.ClasseB()
```

modulo_b:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
         ...
    def cria_a(self):
        import modulo_a
        return modulo_a.ClasseA()
```

Note que não há nenhuma dependencia de importação - e na verdade, esse código funcionria bem mesmo se os `import` estivessem no topo nos modulo_a e modulo_b.

Agora, se eu tivesse criado um novo objeto tipo "A" dentro do "init" da ClasseB - aí seria outra historia - o objeto A ao ser criado cria um objeto B, se o B criasse um A isso criaria um loop infinito sim: mas o problema está na lógica dessa ideia, não na linguagem - se você tentar simplesmente fazer um teste de mesa e ir anotando os objetos que são criados quando você cria um objeto A dessa forma, vai ver que estará tentando criar infinitos objetos - não importa se em Python, Assembler, C, ou Portugol.

Comment: É bem isso mesmo, obrigado, vou dar uma olhada. Eu modifiquei um pouco a pergunta quando você estava me respondendo para que ficasse mais claro, agora mudou um pouco o nome dos módulos, mas a ideia é a mesma.